# How to invoke the popup menu for the tab page (not for the tab control) and select Cut opt in powerbuilder?

Tags: powerbuilder

I am using a tabcontrol in powerbuilder and i need to invoke the popupemnu for the tabpage for deletion purpose.can any one help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the PopMenu() function.

Answer (score 0):

In the IDE click the tab to make sure the correct page is showing. Then right-click in the body of the tab to get the page popup.

Comment: @Remi: If it addressed your issue, you should [accept the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/65088/173356)